# How to design claims based identity system for multi tenant application with Okta in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, identity, claims-based-identity, okta

I have a multi tenant application that is using claims based identity management with Windows AD. A single user CAN have access to multiple tenants which he/she can simply switch by selecting a different tenant from a dropdown (with same credentials) in the header.

Lets say I have features A, B, C in my application that I want to restrict access to. And I have clients ACME1 and ACME2. How can I design the identity role/claims setup so that a user can access features A and B for ACME1 and the same user can access only B and C features for ACME2.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your custom authorization server to return dynamic claims, using Okta Expressions.  Docs here:

https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/set-up-authz-server#create-claims-optional

With this you can use group names, such as company_a, and put users in the groups of the companies they have access to.  You would then configure the authorization server to return groups as scope during authentication.

Comment: It appears the link you provided links back to this SO question…